# Load data with ProgressBar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in my project that fill with custom adapter, how to load data from adapter into `RecyclerView` with `ProgressBar`
adapter in activity :

```
adapter = new HistoryAdapter(this, MOMENTS);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want when `ProgressBar` be full (100%) `RecyclerView` fill with adapter ...

Comment: I assume you populate your adapter with data fetched via a network call and you would have been using some async task for that. So set the adapter before you get the data. show progress bar and after you get the data set data in the adapter and then call notifyDatasetChanged() and then finally hide progress

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many data will be in recycler view, just update your progress bar, when a data is added, and calulate the progress.

There is a setProgress method, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

If you dont know ow many data will be in your adapter, I think that you can not shw a correct value.